# Upload text file from android app to php server

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I am trying to upload text file from Android Studio to server. I want to upload all text files in internal storage using repeating alarm manager(I have set already) and network change listener (I have set already in networkchangelistener.php file, where I am trying to deploy this code, if internet is connected, upload files) to PHP server, so no button click will be used.

There is a textFile.txt placed inside Internal storage.

```
String url = "https://path-to/file-upload3.php";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "/textFile.txt");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code is not working, there is no errors showing either. How to select file in Internal storage?

Below I have working code of file-upload3.php, which can successfully upload text file if sent from simple PHP form.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if (
    $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "txt"
) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF and TXT files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    //echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `am trying to upload text file from Android Studio to server.` Dont think so. You are trying that with your Android app on an Android device.

Comment: You should use file.exists() and file.canRead() before you try to upload.

Comment: How to read a text file from Internal storage (root folder)?

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "textFile.txt");
 passed file.exists() check however fails file.canRead() check.

Comment: If you cannot read a file you cannot open an inputstream for it too. Or at least when you try to read you will get an ioexception.  See the stack trace.

Comment: Since Android 10 direct access to most external storage directories is prohibited, you have to use scope storage API instead.

Comment: Ordinary request is not working for the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. This permission must be set in Android setting by user. Go to App Info > App Permissions > Files and media permission > Allow management of all files. It can access file text. Now it can read text files.